# Get all Facebook pages by Facebook's Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get all Facebook pages using the graph API?
I have tried to read the graph API documentation but I couldn't figure out how to retrieve all Facebook pages. 
If it is possible, can you please show me how to do it?

Comment: No there is no way to get the millions and millions of page IDs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have one more question, i want for example to get pages of my country  in order to do statistics, like the service provided by social backer , is there o way to select  the most 100 popular pages in a country using graph api ?

Comment: No there is no API like that